# plotly - iplot() on google colab does not work

Tags: plotly, google-colaboratory, iplots

When I use iplot() in google colab. I'm not having error and I can't get any result too. It just runs it, but brings nothing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from plotly import __version__
pip install plotly cufflinks
!pip install plotly --upgrade

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import 
download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns="A B C D".split())
df.iplot()
```